# TypeError: Unsafe NumPy casting, you must explicitly cast Python strings mixed with "" strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, floating-point

I have a data in the format of a DF that looks like:

```
             time_slice    A  B  C
0   2014-01-23 14:30:00  1    A 1.15
1   2014-01-23 14:30:00  1    B 2.15
2   2014-01-23 14:30:00  1    C 18.1
3   2014-01-23 14:30:00  1    D 1
5   2014-01-23 14:30:00  1    F "1,100.14"
```

All the elements in DF['C'] should be cast into floats (which they are). Right now, they are produced as strings, but some strings have "" and some don't. I can see these strings in Notepad - in python viewer all numbers look the same, without ""
pd.Float64Index(DF['C']) provides the above error.
Help please? :-(

Comment: the one that is still is string has a comma separator, you should remove all these first before casting to a float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
>>> df['C'].str.replace(',', '').astype('float64')
0       1.15
1       2.15
2      18.10
3       1.00
5    1100.14
Name: C, dtype: float64
>>> pd.Float64Index(_)
Float64Index([1.15, 2.15, 18.1, 1.0, 1100.14], dtype='float64')
```

Comment: Worked like a miracle. Thanks.